# How to assign session value to instance variable in Rspec controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, rspec

My rails code as follow:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @session_is_admin = session[:user_permission][:is_admin]
    begin
      @obj = Class.all
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
      end
    rescue
    end
  end
end
```

Rspec Code: under (rspec/controllers)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MyController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "populates an array of data" do
       get :index
       session[:user_permission][:is_admin] = false
       assigns(:session_is_admin).should eq(false)
    end
  end
end
```

After execution it provide me following error:

```
 1) MyController GET index populates an array of data
     Failure/Error: get :index
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/my_controller.rb:16:in `index'
     # ./spec/controllers/my_controller_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 9.27 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Please help me to resolve above issue. It is due to session value assignment not successfully done by my rspec code.

Comment: try adding `session[:user_permission] = {}` before assigning `false`

Comment: try using session_is_admin at the place of @session_is_admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to set the session value *before* calling the controller action. Also your session setup only works if `session[:user_permission]` is already a `Hash`.

Try the following instead:

```
it "populates an array of data" do
  session[:user_permission] = {:is_admin => false}
  get :index
  assigns(:session_is_admin).should eq(false)
end
```